# passive motion in opengl

Tags: opengl, line

i am trying to draw a line with passive motion of mouse (it's from a book) but i can't manage to do it.

```
float xf, yf, xs, ys;
int flag=0;

void setupmywindow()
{
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
    gluOrtho2D(0,100,0,100);
}

void myDisplay()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void move(int x, int y)
{

if( flag == 1)
{
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex2f(xf, yf);
glVertex2f(xs, ys);
glEnd() ;

}
xf = x/500;
yf = (500-y)/500;

xs = x/500;
ys = (500-y)/500;
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glLogicOp(GL_XOR);
glVertex2f(xf, yf);
glVertex2f(xs, ys);
glLogicOp(GL_COPY);

glEnd() ;

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{


    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutCreateWindow("My window");
    setupmywindow();
    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(move);
    glutMainLoop();

}
```

Is sth missing here?

Comment: What is the name of the book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this copied straight from the book? If so I suggest you stop reading it!
In almost all cases, any drawing calls should be done between the start and the end of DisplayFunc. So you should change your program to:

```
float xf, yf, xs, ys;
int flag=0;

void setupmywindow()
{
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
    gluOrtho2D(0,100,0,100);
}

void myDisplay()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    if( flag == 1)
    {
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2f(xf, yf);
        glVertex2f(xs, ys);
        glEnd() ;
    }
    glLogicOp(GL_XOR);

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2f(xf, yf);
    glVertex2f(xs, ys);
    glEnd();

    glLogicOp(GL_COPY);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void move(int x, int y)
{
    xf = x/500.0f;
    yf = (500.0f-y)/500.0f;

    xs = x/500.0f;
    ys = (500.0f-y)/500.0f;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutCreateWindow("My window");
    setupmywindow();
    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(move);
    glutMainLoop();

}
```

EDIT: Ville Krumlinde is of course right, you can't do glLogicOp within a Begin and End clause, I have updated the above code to include the fix.

Comment: I've edited, try this code. And use glCoror3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f). Otherwise it will be interpreted as byte values (where 255 is max).

Answer (score 1):

One error is that you have glLogicOp-calls between glBegin/End pairs. Very few OpenGL calls are allowed between begin and end. Do it like this instead:

```
glLogicOp(GL_XOR);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex2f(xf, yf);
glVertex2f(xs, ys);
glEnd() ;
glLogicOp(GL_COPY);
```

Answer (score 1):

If this code is really from the book then that book is horrible, you should just drop it before it damages your brain and go for something better (and free) like [NeHe tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) instead.

I see for example a serious problem with the lines...

```
xf = x/500;
yf = (500-y)/500;

xs = x/500;
ys = (500-y)/500;
```

you are setting xf, yf and xs, ys to the same values (so your line will be of length 0) ... and moreover given that `x` and `y` are integers those divisions will probably always give you a result of 0.